# Requests vs Selenium Python in Youtube

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests

When I use **`Selenium library`** to find the length of related channel in YouTube channel Page *it gives me 12.* But when I use **`Requests library`** to find the length *it gives me 0*.

I want to use requests please help me if it's possible

My code

#### Requests

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
r = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoykjkkJxsz7JukJR7mGrwg/about")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
bb = soup.find_all("ytd-mini-channel-renderer",class_="style-scope ytd-vertical-channel-section-renderer")
print(len(bb))
```

#### Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoykjkkJxsz7JukJR7mGrwg/about")
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
bb = soup.find_all("ytd-mini-channel-renderer",class_="style-scope ytd-vertical-channel-section-renderer")
print(len(bb))
```

Answer (score 3):

Every time I've run into an issue like this, it was because JS was creating the data I was after. If this is the case, you likely won't be able to use requests as it can't handle the JS.

If you navigate to that youtube page in a browser, you can see that "ytd-mini-channel-renderer" exists if you inspect it, but if you view source, you get 0 results. The code you can see from "view source" is what requests is getting.

Comment: yeah right ! but u know selenium is slow as compared to requests

Comment: i want to do this things using requests

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think a workaround is possible with just requests. Something has to be able to run the javascript. You could try using PhantomJS as it maybe a faster than chrome.

Comment: That's not always the case. I noticed requests can sometimes get different html code. I've posted an example code above

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the issue is caused by the soup object having different tags from the ones you see from dev tools, which is what is happening in your case. On analysing the soup object you'll notice the information you need is actually now in `<h3 class="yt-lockup-title ">`.

This code will pull the results you want:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCoykjkkJxsz7JukJR7mGrwg/about")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
bb=soup.find_all('h3',class_='yt-lockup-title')
print(len(bb))
```