# WebScraping with Python / Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to pull some data from Youtube, but i'm struggling with catching the text, here is my code:

```
username = "unboxtherapy"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Chrome Web Driver/chromedriver.exe')
api_url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/"+username+"/about"
driver.get(api_url)
html = driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html')
soup=bs(html.text,'html.parser')
text=str(soup)
```

In the example above, I'm trying to capture the description shown on the page.

```
soup
```

returns all the text on the page i.e. the description that I want + a ton of other things which I don't want.

```
text
```

returns all the following text:

> "GB\nSIGN IN\nUnbox Therapy\n13,802,667
>   subscribers\nJOIN\nSUBSCRIBE\nTwitter\nHOME\nVIDEOS\nPLAYLISTS\nCOMMUNITY\nCHANNELS\nABOUT\nDescription\nWhere
>   products get naked.\n\nHere you will find a variety of videos
>   showcasing the coolest products on the planet. From the newest
>   smartphone to surprising gadgets and technology you never knew
>   existed. It's all here on Unbox Therapy.\n\nBusiness / professional
>   inquiries ONLY - business [at] unboxtherapy.com\n(please don't use
>   YouTube inbox)\nLinks\nTwitter Facebook Instagram The Official
>   Website\nStats\nJoined Dec 21, 2010\n2,698,921,226 views\nOTHER COOL
>   CHANNELS.\nLew Later\nSUBSCRIBE\nMarques Brownlee\nSUBSCRIBE\nJonathan
>   Morrison\nSUBSCRIBE\nAustin
>   Evans\nSUBSCRIBE\nDetroitBORG\nSUBSCRIBE\nLooneyTek\nSUBSCRIBE\nSoldier
>   Knows Best\nSUBSCRIBE\nUrAvgConsumer\nSUBSCRIBE\nRELATED
>   CHANNELS\nLinus Tech
>   Tips\nSUBSCRIBE\nJerryRigEverything\nSUBSCRIBE\nMrwhosetheboss\nSUBSCRIBE\nTechSmartt\nSUBSCRIBE"

Is there a way to capture just the description? is that possible at all?

Thank you in advance to whoever can help me.

Best Wishes

Comment: you can get element by ID and a quick F12 on youtube shows that the ID you are looking for is `description`

Comment: thank you. When I try: a= driver.find_element_by_id('description'), it returns the text but also a lot of "\n". Is there a way to remove them? here is the text that is returned: "Where products get naked.\n\nHere you will find a variety of videos showcasing the coolest products on the planet. From the newest smartphone to surprising gadgets and technology you never knew existed. It's all here on Unbox Therapy.\n\nBusiness / professional inquiries ONLY - business [at] unboxtherapy.com\n(please don't use YouTube inbox)"

Comment: replace "\n" with new lines? or with spaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code.Let me know if it work.

```
import bs4 as bs
import re
username = "unboxtherapy"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Chrome Web Driver/chromedriver.exe')
api_url = "https://www.youtube.com/user/"+username+"/about"
driver.get(api_url)
html = driver.page_source
soup=bs.BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
findtext=soup.find_all('yt-formatted-string',id=re.compile("description"))
for txt in findtext:
    print(txt.text)
```

Output :

```
Where products get naked.

Here you will find a variety of videos showcasing the coolest products on the planet. From the newest smartphone to surprising gadgets and technology you never knew existed. It's all here on Unbox Therapy.

Business / professional inquiries ONLY - business [at] unboxtherapy.com
(please don't use YouTube inbox)
```

Comment: is there something special with the use of `webdriver`? when i get the html using `requests` i am unable to find the id even though its in the received html. never mind i found [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746085/requests-vs-selenium-python)

Comment: Out of interest, how did you find 'yt-formatted-string' ? (sorry i'm not very knowledgeable about web stuff in general)

Comment: @tezzaaa literraly hit F12 and selected the object in my web browser browser

Comment: @Nullman: I have just done chrome inspect to find the element and then provided the tag name and id value.

Comment: @Nullman thanks I did that also. In Chrome, inspect works well. I'm trying to pull views etc from the same page

Answer (score 1):

Simple parsing can be completed using only selenium.

```
driver.get(api_url)
description = drvier.find_element_by_id('description')
print(description.text)
```

(if you use chrome and know about inspect)
to know the tag name, id or attribute value:

1. just right click on description text (you want to find element)
2. select 'inspect' like this:

[image: like this]

Then you can check value like this:

[image: like this]

- pink color text : tag name
- '#' & orange color text : id
- '.' % blue color text : attribute value

Now use the driver method

```
driver.find_by_elemeent_by_tag_name()  
driver.find_by_elements_by_tag_name()  
driver.find_by_element_id()  
driver.find_by_elements_id()  
driver.find_by_element_class_name()  
driver.find_by_elements_class_name()
```

Comment: thank you very much, that's useful to me and also to other people who are new to parsing :-)