# Why do i get none or empty list when using find or find_all in beautifulsoap even though the tags do contain other tags and data

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to make a coronavirus tracker using beautifulsoup just for some practice. 
my code is,

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page=requests.get("https://sample.com")
soup=BeautifulSoup(page.content,'html.parser')
table=soup.find("div",class_="ZDcxi")

print(table)
```

In the output its showing none, but the div tag with the class ZDcxi do have content.
please help

Comment: Try this, ```table = soup.find("div", {'class': "ZDcxi"})```

Answer (score 0):

The data, which you see in the browser, and includes the target div, is dynamic content, generated by scripts included with the page and run in the browser. If you just search for the class name in `page.content`, you will find it is not there.

What many people do is use `selenium` to open desired pages through Chrome (or another web browser), and then, after the page finishes loading and generating dynamic content, use `BeautifulSoup` to harvest the content from the browser, and continue processing from there.

Find out more at [Requests vs Selenium Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46746085/requests-vs-selenium-python), and also when you search [selenium vs requests](https://www.google.com/search?q=selenium%20vs%20requests&rlz=1C1GCEA_enIL793IL793&oq=selenium%20vs%20re&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l6.4634j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)/